# Passing an NSArray from Objc to Swift Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, nsarray

im trying to work with the following pods file in an objective c project:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSDropDown

I've modified the coco file to ensure all attributes are public and have the @objc tag

However, I am attempting to perform the following Swift function in Objective c and I continue to receive the following error messages:

Swift Code Im trying to execute in objective c

```
dropDown.optionArray = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
```

The objc code

```
NSArray * stringArray = @[@"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3"];
[_dropDown setOptionArray: stringArray];
```

And I continue to get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[iOSDropDown.DropDown setOptionArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a90048800'
```

I understand that NSArray is a coco specific object that should transfer between swift and objc but im not sure why I am unable to set the optionArray property without crashing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use `dropDown.setOptionsArray(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])` instead?

Comment: Thanks for responding moe but that syntax is swift, I tried the equivelent in obj c but i get the same error message [_dropDown setOptionArray: @[@"1", @"2", @"3"]];

Comment: Is your synthesized method working properly? If the array property is not read-only, you could just try setting it from objc: `dropDown.optionArray = @[ ... ];`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the swift object was of an array and not an NSArray. My solution to this was to create a helper variable in swift that takes in an NSArray and sets the optionArray var within swift:

```
@IBInspectable public var arraySetter = NSArray() {
    didSet{
        let objCArray = NSMutableArray(array: self.arraySetter)

        if let swiftArray = objCArray as NSArray as? [String] {
            // Use swiftArray here
            self.optionArray = swiftArray
        }
    }
}
```